# How to resize live comments div in Angular 2 / Ionic 2

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to create a live comment feed that constantly updates with new comments. I want to limit the size of the comments area and would like the comments to disappear from the DOM once a certain max. number of comments is reached.

For example, where the lowest comments is the newest and the first comment in the stack is no longer fully visible :

```
<div class="liveComments" scroll="true" text-wrap>

  <ion-row class="liveComment" *ngFor="let cm of comments;" >

      <ion-col col-2 col-md-2><img src="https://website.com/uploads/user/avatar/49420/shades.jpg" class="liveProfile"/></ion-col>

      <ion-col col-3 col-md-3 class="usernameLiveComment"> {{username}}</ion-col>

      <ion-col col-7 col-md-7>  <span>{{cm.comment}} </span> </ion-col>

  </ion-row>

  <ion-row align="center">

      <ion-col col-12 col-md-12><img src="assets/imgs/spinner.gif" width="15%" align="center" /></ion-col>

  </ion-row>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of comments and push/slice/pop entries. The binding does the job for you.

Offtopic: Make a fancy animation with `:enter` and `:leave`

Alternativly you can use a `virtual-scroll` list so the dom manipulation is done by the ionic magic